# Issue with outputting scoring result in a Craps game

Tags: javascript, numbers, scoring

I'm working on a somewhat simply dice game but I can't get it to display the alert popup when I click the button.

I'm also trying to figure out the simplest way to check if housescore or myscore = maxscore then alert "congratulations, you win" or "sorry, you lost"

Here is my code:

```js
var myscore = 0;
var maxScore = 100;
var housescore = 0;

function rollDice() {
  var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
  var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;

  if (x + y == 7 || 11) {
    housescore = (housescore + 10);
    alert("CRAPS" + " Your Score is " + "Player: " + myscore + "House: " + housescore);
  } else if (x == y && x + y == isEven(n)) {
    myscore = (myscore + 10);
    alert("Even Up" + " Your Score is " + "Player: " + myscore + "House: " + housescore);
  }
  if (x == y && x + y == isOdd(n)) {
    housescore = (housescore + 10);
    alert("Odd Ball" + " Your Score is " + "Player: " + myscore + "House: " + housescore);
  } else {
    alert("You rolled a " + x + " and a " + y + " Your Score is " + "Player: " + myscore + "House: " + housescore);
  }
}

function isEven(n) {
  return n % 2 == 0;
}

function isOdd(n) {
  return Math.abs(n % 2) == 1;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Roll The Dice" onClick="rollDice()" />
```

Comment: What is `n` in `isEven(n)` & `isOdd(n)`?

Comment: How can x be 7 or y be 11 if they are numbers from 1 to 6

Comment: im not 100% sure i pulled that particular function from another stackoverflow question..basically the medulo method which is what those functions are is the best way to determine if a number is odd or even.

Comment: James good catch I need to write if (x + y == 7 || 11) instead I will correct initial code

Comment: `var sum = x + y; if (sum == 7  || sum == 11) ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I think you're after.  I broke down your ifs to handle both cases where x == y in one branch, and used a simple mod operation to determine whether a die roll was even, and an else to handle the odd die rolls.

```js
var myscore = 0;
var maxScore = 100;
var housescore = 0;

function rollDice() {
  var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
  var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
  
  var total = x + y;
  msg = "You rolled " + x + "," + y + " = " + total + "\n";

  if (total == 7 || total == 11) {
    housescore += 10;
    msg += "CRAPS";
  } else if (x == y) { // this condition contains two possible outcomes, handle both within this else if
    if (x % 2 == 0) {
      myscore += 10;
      msg += "Even Up";
    } else {
      housescore += 10;
      msg += "Odd Ball";
    }
  }
  msg += " Your Score is " + "Player: " + myscore + ", House: " + housescore;
  alert(msg);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <input type="button" value="Roll The Dice" onClick="rollDice()" />
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @mplungjan I wasn't planning on doing a full refactor!  I fixed those two hopefully that will stop your eyes from bleeding.

Comment: Thanks man, this help is priceless I am just learning the basics of javascript and you guys are great help with helping me learn how to properly write stuff like this.

Comment: How do I incorporate function this function into my script so the player knows when them or the house won?  Here:s the code: didIwin() {
 if (housescore >= 100) {
 alert ("Sorry the house won!");
 } else if (playerscore >= 100) {
 alert ("Congratulations you won!");
 }
}

Comment: You should call didIwin after every roll, so after or before the alert you could add didIwin(); into the existing rollDice function.

Answer (score 1):

Code like this is wrong:

```
if (x == y && x + y == isEven(n))
```

You haven't declared an `n` variable. And it makes no sense to compare the addition of two numbers to the `true` or `false` value that `isEven()` and `isOdd()` return. I think what you meant was:

```
if (x == y && isEven(x + y))
```

But when the two numbers are equal, adding them together will always be even, so I'm not sure what the point of that test is. Maybe you mean:

```
if (x == y && isEven(x))
```

I'm not familiar with a rule in Craps where the house or player win depending on whether equal dice are even or odd.

This is also wrong:

```
if (x == 7 && y == 11)
```

`x` and `y` are numbers from `1` to `6`, so they can't be `7` or `11`. In craps you add the two dice, so this should be:

```
if (x + y == 7 || x + y == 11)
```

There's little need for both `isEven()` and `isOdd()` functions -- a number is odd if it's not even.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<input type="button" value="Roll The Dice" onClick="rollDice()" />
<br />

<script type="text/javascript">
var score = 0;
var maxScore = 50;
var rolls = 0;
var maxRolls = 20;


function rollDice()
{
    var x = Math.floor( Math.random() * 6 ) + 1;
    var y = Math.floor( Math.random() * 6 ) + 1;

    if( x == y )
    {
        score = getScore( x );
        alert("You threw a Double " + x + " Your Score is "+ score);
    }
    else
    {
        alert("You threw a " + x + " and a " + y + " Your Score is " + score);
    }

    rolls++;

    if (rolls == maxRolls && score < maxScore)
    {
        alert("Sorry You Lose!");
        score = 0;
        rolls = 0;
        return;
    }
    else if (score >= maxScore)
    {
        alert("Congratulations You Win!");
        score = 0;
        rolls = 0;
        return;
    }
}

function getScore(x)
{
    switch( x )
    {
        case 1:
            score += 5;
            break;
        case 2:
            score += 5;
            break;
        case 3:
            score = 0;
            break;
        case 4:
            score += 5;
            break;
        case 5:
            score += 5;
            break;
        case 6:
            score += 25;
            break;
    }

    return score;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
</html>
```